# How can I search for multiple values in a table using space in Typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

*please check the image attached. I want to sort search result by mulitple keywords. Suppose i want search users who are both basic and India, I can do that by just entering " basic india"*

*I am using following code Snippet to filter single keywords:*

```
  if(value) {
            this.filteredList = _.filter(userList, (a) =>
                (a as any).fullName.indexOf(value) >= 0 || (a as any).email.indexOf(value) >= 0 ||
                 (a as any).memberShipType.indexOf(value) >= 0 || (a as any).userType.indexOf(value) >= 0 ||
                  (a as any).countryName.indexOf(value) >= 0 || (a as any).city && (a as any).city.indexOf(value) >= 0 
                  || (a as any).state &&(a as any).state.indexOf(value) >= 0
            );
            this.filteredusercount = this.filteredList.length;
```

*[HOW CAN I SEARCH FOR ANY TWO OR VALUES FROM THE COLUMNS SEPARATED BY SPACE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdveZ.jpg)*

Comment: can you elaborate your question .add some code and what your trying and you want?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please take the tour to get on the right track https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @JagadeeshGovindaraj  please check the image attached. I want to sort search result by mulitple keywords. Suppose i want search users who are both basic and India, I can do that by just entering " basic india"

Comment: @pratyushkumar. just take look at how to ask a question and how to express your problem to another developer. please read this blogs it will help you to understand the StackOverflow culture.https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/10/04/asking-better-questions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

split your inputs to array.

```
var searchQuery = "text to split";
    var items = searchQuery.split(" ");
    var filterlist = userList;
    items.forEach(element => {
      if (element) {
        filterlist = _.filter(filterlist, (a) =>
          (a as any).fullName.indexOf(element) >= 0 || (a as any).email.indexOf(element) >= 0 ||
          (a as any).memberShipType.indexOf(element) >= 0 || (a as any).userType.indexOf(element) >= 0 ||
          (a as any).countryName.indexOf(element) >= 0 || (a as any).city && (a as any).city.indexOf(element) >= 0
          || (a as any).state && (a as any).state.indexOf(element) >= 0
        );
      }
    });
    yourGridList=filterlist;
```

**before you loop the value first you need to check string have space .if no space then you dont need to loop**

*Hope this help to you*

Comment: This works but if you enter something wrong the we get an empty table, beacuse it doesn't exist in the data, also the value doesn't reset.

Comment: if the result is empty then you need to show no data found in toast, and don't assign a filter result into the main array.gotcha.

Answer (score 1):

Above ans is correct. But it doesn't reset the result if we change the value. we can restore the search result if you rectify/change the value by adding the following code along with it:

1[HTML FILE]. Pass backspace event from input field:

`<input class="c-input" type="text" placeholder="Search User" name="First Name" (input)="searchUser($event.target.value, $event)">`

2[TYPESCRIPT FILE]. In your function check whether it is backspace:

`if(event.inputType == "deleteContentBackward"){
            this.filteredList = this.userList;
        }`